# What is "a fresh spin on laundry day"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

This is written on an ad card:

> *Dirty Laundry, a fresh spin on laundry day.*

Explain, please, the meaning of it.

Answer (score 3):

The capitalization of "Dirty Laundry" suggests that this is an advertisement for a movie, TV show, play, or book. IMdb shows that there are two recent TV shows around the world with this title: one from [2016](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5745220/), another from [2017](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt6079970/), so I suspect it's an ad for one of them (or maybe something I didn't find).

The later reference to "laundry day" implies that the story involves people doing laundry.

As stated in the other answer, "fresh spin" is an idiom meaning a new, interesting way of looking at something.

Taken as a whole, this is saying that this TV show is about interesting, probably unexpected, things happening at a laundry.

It also makes use of two puns: cleaning laundry makes it fresh, and washing machines have a spin cycle. Puns are very popular in slogans.

Answer (score 2):

This expression is full of double entendres.

Let me explain the individual meanings:

"Dirty laundry" - An expression that could mean literally dirty clothes that must be washed.  It could also mean something you don't wish to do, aka, "I helped you once already with your homework, but don't expect me to take care of your dirty laundry again."

"A fresh spin" - An expression that could mean literally a "refreshing spin" which brings to mind the spin of a washing machine used to clean clothes.  "A fresh spin" is also an expression that means "a new take" on something.  "Rotisserie chicken offered in grocery stores offers a fresh spin on cooked chicken."

Put these meanings together, and you can take it to mean "Dirty Laundry is a new way to think about doing laundry."  The expression "Dirty Laundry" fits the theme as the general theme is about laundry.  "A fresh spin" fits as well, as in a real sense it is a literal "fresh spin" in how laundry is cleaned.

Comment: Good answer but I don't think 'dirty laundry' is metaphor for something you don't want to do but instead something you want to keep hidden.

Comment: I agree with what @EllieK said. I just checked several dictionaries, and couldn't find a single entry using the idiom to mean "an unwanted chore." However, I did find: _personal matters that could be embarrassing if made public; private, personal matters, especially that which may be embarrassing; unflattering facts or questionable activities that one wants to remain secret._ (I suppose it could be used figuratively, but that's not how it's typically used.)

Comment: @J. R. Doing laundry is an unwanted chore for many people.  ***It is not that words dirty laundry mean an unwanted chore***. You misunderstood what Neil said. He never said it was a metaphor, it is a real thing and a  pain in the patoutie [my coinage].

Comment: @Lambie, but the example illustrates doing something that you don't want to do; I imagine the helping with homework is not a secret that needs to hidden from the world.

Comment: @Lambie Laundry is often an unwanted chore, unfortunately, no one said anything about doing laundry.  Neil gave a nod toward the literal usage, everything beyond the literal is metaphor.

Comment: @EllieK never mind. I think his explanation was excellent. "I don't want to help you with your dirty laundry" could be something you don't want to do, whatever it is. Hide it, do it, deal with it, etc. Literal or not.

Comment: @Lambie - RE: "It is not that words dirty laundry mean an unwanted chore." Except that's exactly what this answer says: _"Dirty laundry" .. could also mean something you don't wish to do_.  If someone wants to use a metaphorical household chore to refer to helping with homework, then I'd advise picking a different chore, as _dirty laundry_ has another meaning and connotation, and **learners deserve to know that meaning**. As for what I said about a metaphor, I was trying to give Neil the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @jr Yes. It is well and good to invent a new metaphor. But it is a very bad idea to take an existing, well-known idiom and try to use it in a totally different way. Even if the metaphor might be very apt if the established meaning didn't exist. It's just likely to confuse the reader.